# Create a simple plugin to show ACF in wordpress posts (if they exists)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

After installed ACF plugin in wordpress website, and configured some custom fields, I'd like to show ACF custom fields only if they exists in my posts (articles).
I followed the guide but can't find how to do it without using a child theme. I need to create an action performing even if the theme will be updated without losing my code. I'd like to have a simple plugin who can add my code below to my posts. I am not very familiar with php yet. This is my code that I inserted in a single-template:

```
<div id="scheda-dettagli-vino" class="dettagli-vino">
                    <table>
          <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php if (get_field('produttore'))
                            { echo '<img src="/downloads/area-di-produzione.png" />' , '<h3 style="display:inline; ">Area di produzione</h3>';}?>
                        </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php if(get_field('produttore'))
                                            {   echo the_field('produttore');}?>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

          </table>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you need to create a folder in the plugin directory and create a file in which the extension must be folder-name.php.

I share a sample code you just paste it. After active plugin. Hopefully, work it.

Example Folder Name: **acf-helper**

Example Plugin: **acf-helper.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: ACF-Helper
 * Plugin URI: #
 * Description: Custom plugin for ACF.
 * Author: Monzur Alam
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Text Domain: acf-helper
 * License: GPLv2
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

if (!function_exists('acf_helper_content')) {
    function acf_helper_content( $content ){
        if(is_singular('post')){
            ob_start();
            ?>
            <div id="scheda-dettagli-vino" class="dettagli-vino">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php 
                                if (get_field('produttore')) {
                                    echo '<img src="/downloads/area-di-produzione.png" />', '<h3 style="display:inline; ">Area di produzione</h3>';
                                } 
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php 
                                if (get_field('produttore')) {
                                    echo esc_html(the_field('produttore'));
                                }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
            <?php
            return $content . ob_get_clean();
        }
    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'acf_helper_content');
}
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!! I love yu

Comment: You are welcome. @Ashyzan

Comment: purtroppo pages appears blank :(

Comment: Please check your custom field names & update them into code.
if you want to show data without check just try it.
https://pastebin.com/tDVaLysj

Comment: the problem is that the posts are seen correctly, while the pages have problems. I thought the code would only run on articles and not pages. I'm working with a complicated template like newspaper theme and when I edit the pages with their builder I get it wrong. Actually on the posts I don't use the builder so it would be fine, but the error complicate all. theme --> [link](https://forum.tagdiv.com/api-single-template-introduction/)

Comment: - the error Is : Error at rows: 8(models) : 1(dom). The model does not match the content Current state has involved an issue. You could try an UNDO operation (CTRL+Z / CTRL+SHIFT+Z) and is documented here [link](https://forum.tagdiv.com/tagdiv-composer-not-working/)

Comment: I run the ACF helper in my test site, so see now article looks well at this link [link](https://www.studiocreativo69.it/come-creare-un-sito-web-2018/) but pages are blank [link](https://www.studiocreativo69.it/) . I replaced all code with this:

Comment: [https://pastebin.com/cEAHYp5M](https://pastebin.com/cEAHYp5M)

Comment: Do you want to show it on the page?

Comment: Hi Monzur, no, I don't want to display on page. There is something wrong because pages are blank, except for header and footer. Any suggests?